# Символы в строке, которые встречаются 1 раз

Tags: java

Вот сделал задачку, но почему-то не работает, помогите, пожалуйста, разобрать ошибки.

Смысл задачи найти в строке символы, которые встречаются 1 раз.

```
 package org.jazzteam;

    public class ArbitrarySymbols {
        public static String one() {
            String l = "";
            String str = "hello Wrold";
            int count = 0;
            int count1 = 0;
            char chars[] = str.toCharArray();
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++) {
                    if (chars[i] == chars[j]) {

                        count++;
                    }

                }
                if (count > 1) {
                } else {
                    l += str.charAt(i);
                    count = 0;
                }
            }
            return l;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println(one());

        }
    }
```

Comment: @Wengelm, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: это что открыли набор на курсы? пару дней назад точно такая  же задача была

Comment: Нет набора нету :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static String one() {
        String l = "";
        String str = "hello World";
        int count = 0;
        char chars[] = str.toCharArray();

        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < str.length(); j++){
                if (chars[i] == chars[j] && i != j){
                    count++;
                }
            }

            if (count < 1){
                l += str.charAt(i);
            } else {
                count = 0;
            }
        }

        return l;
    }
```

Comment: т.е. у меня была ошибка в том, что я счетчику не возвращал значение 0 и не проверял дополнительное условие  когда i было не равно j? Я просто сам обучаюсь Java. Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте массив счетчиков размером в мощность множества Ваших символов. (по простому  - Русская 'я' имеет десятичный код 1103 так что возьмите на свой вкус, допустим 2048).

Инициализируйте его нулями. Просматриваете строку **один** раз (!), используя символ как индекс в массиве счетчиков инкрементируете счетчик.

В конце пробегаете по массиву счетчиков и выводите те индексы (как символы) для которых счетчик равен 1.

**И никаких вложенных циклов** в подобных задачах.

Comment: прикинь, когда-то виде такую реализацию, там в коде был класс, в котором был алфавит и в нем каждой букве соответствовало число, потом сравнивалось туда-сюда, короче, это ппц =)

ЗЫ пусть аффтор ищет похожий ответ, там красивая реализация предложена

Comment: Автор только начинает учиться, поэтому я не стал предлагать ему HashMap(), но предостерег от принципиально плохого (в общем случае) алгоритма.

Comment: Ну тогда и не надо советов про 2048. Вдруг он захочет по-грузински написать? Или ещё на каком хитром языке. Правда в ucs-2 всего-то возможно 2^16 символов.

Comment: @alexlz, Вы считаете, что используемый автором алгоритм *это нормально* ?

Comment: Да нет. Просто я не считаю HashMap таким страшным, чтобы им новичков пугать. Школьники на php используют, и сообщений о производственных травмах что-то не видно

Comment: OK. Тогда пусть автор применяет такой метод (массив счетчиков) для ASCII символов (0..127)

Comment: ![alt text][1]


  [1]: http://i.imgur.com/4c1nd.png